# How to automatically update table, whenever data added to another table?

Tags: mysql, java

I have created two tables in MySQL. One (`Todo_tbl`) holds the data while the other (`Statistics_tbl`) hold the sums one of the variables from `Todo_tbl`.

Following the definitions of these tables:

```
create table Todo_tbl (
id INT auto_increment,
person VARCHAR(45) ,
task VARCHAR(45) ,
duration INT(4),
deadline_day VARCHAR(2),
deadline_month VARCHAR(2),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into Todo_tbl values(1,'John', 'dust the floors', 40,04,03);
insert into Todo_tbl values(2,'Matt', 'do the dishes', 15,02,02);
insert into Todo_tbl values(3,'Mary', 'dusting', 40,03,02);
insert into Todo_tbl values(4,'Chloe', 'cleaning the windows', 75,04,05);
insert into Todo_tbl values(5,'John', 'wash the floors', 60,03,03);
insert into Todo_tbl values(6,'Bridget', 'take out the trash', 15,03,03);
insert into Todo_tbl values(7,'Matt', 'do the laundry', 18,02,02);
insert into Todo_tbl values(8,'Bridget', 'water the plants', 15,03,03);

select * from Todo_tbl;


create table Statistics_tbl (
SELECT person, SUM(duration) as total_duration FROM Todo_tbl GROUP BY person
);

select * from Statistics_tbl;
```

The problem is that whenever I add new data to the `Todo_tbl`, it is not considered in the `Statistics_tbl`.

Is there any way to connect two tables, so that when there is a change in one, the other will respond as well?

Comment: See `TRIGGERs` as a way to update a table when another table is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a table to hold the statistics when you have a perfectly good query that can get you the same thing from the original table?

Databases like to stick to a concept known as the "Single Source of Truth".
One table (or a group of them) holds the fundamental data.  If that's wrong, *everything's* wrong.  In this case, that's your todo_tbl.

If you need another table that has to be kept in step with todo_tbl - however that's done - then you run the *risk* of the two getting out of step and misrepresenting what's what.

Suggestion: Pop an index on Todo_tbl.person (may help with the grouping) and use the select statement you already have to get the statistics as the heart of a *View* that gets you the statistics data straight from the Single Source of Truth.

```
CREATE VIEW statistics_v AS
SELECT 
  person 
, SUM( duration ) as total_duration 
FROM todo_tbl 
GROUP BY person ;
```